# cleartool settask for a TASK related query

Tags: clearcase

Using "`cleartool settask`" command one can select a TASK within a view.
How to query for a TASK being used in all the different VIEW?

A TASK can be selected in multiple VIEW by using the "cleartool settask" command.

I want to find out which all views have selected a particular TASK.
How to query for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to:

- list all views
- for each view, use [`cleartool lstask -view <aviewtag>`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstask.htm?lang=en)
- for each lstask, grep for the particular task.

> The `lstask` command lists the tasks that are associated with a view (base ClearCase).